# Prevent adding line break tags in contenteditable div on enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `contenteditable` div and I want on enter press, add `new line` charcter in text.

I do this:

```
$("#editable").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '\n');
    }
});
```

This works, but this also adds `<br>` tag to text (and in chrome `<div>` tag)

I need prevent adding this tags on enter press.

I know 2 ways:

1) use `preventDefault()` method, but with this method, user needs 2 times press enter key for   line break. this is bad.

2) remove this tags from whole text, using `replace()` method, but in this case, all these tags (also if user specially typed in text) will be removed, so this is also bad approach.

How can   fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#editable").on("keydown", function(e) {
      return e.which != 13; 
});
```